# HTML5 Canvas does not draw lines. WebSockets sharing canvas board

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, websocket, html5-canvas

hope you'll are good. I'm making a simple board shared with canvas and web sockets (Java on the server, not node). I have already made the shared of the draw to the different clients that get into the webpage. The problem is that, when we draw, the canvas start drawing like this ... (see the picture)

[CANVAS WRONG DRAWING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56W5E.jpg)

I don't know why. I'm sending the mousemove and mousedown coordiantes to the server with json, and it returns me the same jsons coordinates that I'm sending... I think the problem is when I received the response, the canvas doesnt draw correctly.

Here's my canvas code:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    console.log("THE DOC IS READY :)");
    drawing();
    connect();
});

var start = {};
var draw = {};
var close = {};
var myCanvas;
var ctx;
var dimensionProps;

function drawing() {
    myCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
    setProps(myCanvas, 800, 500);
    dimensionProps = {
        left: myCanvas.offsetLeft,
        top: myCanvas.offsetTop
    };
    if (myCanvas) {
        let mouseisDown = false;
        var cPosX, cPosY;
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        $(myCanvas).mousedown((e) => {
            mouseisDown = true;
            start.x = e.pageX;
            start.y = e.pageY;
            console.log("start"+JSON.stringify(start))
            sendDraw(start);
            //startDraw(start.x,start.y)
        }).mousemove((e) => {
            if (mouseisDown) {
                draw.x = e.pageX;
                draw.y = e.pageY;
                console.log("drawing"+JSON.stringify(draw))
                sendDraw(draw);
                //drawingCanvas(draw.x,draw.y)
            }
        }).mouseup((e) => {
            mouseisDown = false;
        });
    }
    clear(ctx, myCanvas);
}

const setProps = (canvas, w, h) => {
    canvas.width = w;
    canvas.height = h;
}

const clear = (ctx, canvas) => {
    $("#clear-btn").click(() => {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    });
}

// cross-browser canvas coordinates
const drawingPos = (pPos, dProps) => ((pPos) - (dProps));
```

And this is the websocket (where I received the coordinates from the java backend is "onmessage"):

```
var ws;

const sendDraw = (coord) => ws.send(JSON.stringify(coord));

const close = () => ws.close;

function connect() {
    ws = new WebSocket("ws://" + location.host + "/Board_Project/chatsv");

    ws.onmessage = (e) => {   
        var mydraw = JSON.parse(e.data);
        console.log("this is what i received " + JSON.stringify(mydraw)); //the same coordiantes that I send
        startDraw(mydraw.x,mydraw.y);
        drawingCanvas(mydraw.x, mydraw.y);
        //endDraw();
    }  

    ws.onopen = (e) => {  
        console.log("SUCCESSFULLY CONNECTION");
    }

    ws.onclose = (e) => {
        if (ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
            console.log("THE CONNECTION HAS FINISHED");
        }
    }

    ws.onerror = (e) => {
        console.log("error al conectar");
    }
}   

const startDraw = (x, y) => {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black"; 
    cPosX = x - dimensionProps.left;
    cPosY = y - dimensionProps.top;
    //ctx.moveTo(x,y); //it works
    ctx.moveTo(cPosX,cPosY);
}

const drawingCanvas = (x, y) => {
    cPosX = x - dimensionProps.left;
    cPosY = y - dimensionProps.top;     
    ctx.lineTo(cPosX+10,cPosY+10);
    ctx.stroke();
}

const endDraw = () => ctx.closePath();
```

I dont post the code of the java server because it only get the json, and send it again. So I think it is not neccesary to post it..

Hope you can help me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You said "server only get the json, and send it again."

Well, the point is you need to make mousemove differ from mousedown when ws.onmessage.

Your webSocket can not tell the differences of mousedown and mousemove.
Both mousedown and mousemove listeners call sendDraw().

```
 $(myCanvas).mousedown((e) => {
    mouseisDown = true;
    /* ...*/
    sendDraw(start);
    //startDraw(start.x,start.y)
}).mousemove((e) => {
    if (mouseisDown) {
        /* ...*/
        sendDraw(draw);
        //drawingCanvas(draw.x,draw.y)
    }
})
```

When your webSocket got the message from server, it will always call both startDraw() and drawingCanvas().
No matter it trigger by mousemove or mousedown.

```
ws.onmessage = (e) => {
    var mydraw = JSON.parse(e.data);
    console.log("this is what i received " + JSON.stringify(mydraw)); //the same coordiantes that I send
    startDraw(mydraw.x,mydraw.y);
    drawingCanvas(mydraw.x, mydraw.y);
    //endDraw();
}
```

So, you can use the mouseisDown of ws.onmessage or add some tags when calling sendDraw.

```
ws.onmessage = (e) => {
    var mydraw = JSON.parse(e.data);
    if(mouseisDown){
        drawingCanvas(mydraw.x, mydraw.y);
    } else {
        startDraw(mydraw.x,mydraw.y);
    }
    //endDraw();
}
```

Comment: Hi @Guest, what u said worked, now I can have the full drawing. But now, it does not show what I draw in the other client (I still receiving the json from the server with coordinates, and if i remove the condition i worked but the way that i specified on the question). Maybe for the conditional, i'have tried declaring a flag but it does not worked. Thanks, hope you can answer me

Comment: @TELPRO Try to add tag of sendDraw(start, state). (state--for example--can be 'startDraw' or 'drawing'). 
Pass the state to server and send to client.  
if(mydraw.state == 'drawing'){
    drawingCanvas(/**/);
}else if (mydraw.state == 'startDraw'){
    startDraw(/**/);
}

Comment: Oh god! Thank u so much!! it worked, it was so simple, I've tried something like that before, but didnt work. Thank u again! +1

Comment: @TELPRO Glad to help you